# Rails test giving me an error of "undefined method 'body' "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd

I am writing tests for my rails application. I wrote tests when I finished the user model for my project. The tests were working fine when I wrote them a few months back, however, I am getting the same error on 15 different tests. The errors are given below.

```
1) Error:
UserTest#test_email_should_be_present:
NoMethodError: undefined method `body' for #<User:0x00000008c84238>
    test/models/user_test.rb:21:in `block in <class:UserTest>'


  2) Error:
UserTest#test_should_be_valid:
NoMethodError: undefined method `body' for #<User:0x00000008caebf0>
    test/models/user_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:UserTest>'


  3) Error:
UserTest#test_name_should_not_be_too_long:
NoMethodError: undefined method `body' for #<User:0x00000008cb5068>
    test/models/user_test.rb:26:in `block in <class:UserTest>'


  4) Error:
UserTest#test_associated_scoreboards_should_be_destroyed:
NoMethodError: undefined method `body' for #<User:0x00000008cc2650>
    test/models/user_test.rb:69:in `block in <class:UserTest>'


  5) Error:
UserTest#test_email_addresses_should_be_unique:
NoMethodError: undefined method `body' for #<User:0x00000008cce4f0>
    test/models/user_test.rb:55:in `block in <class:UserTest>'


  6) Error:
UserTest#test_email_validation_should_accept_valid_addresses:
NoMethodError: undefined method `body' for #<User:0x00000008cdf318>
    test/models/user_test.rb:39:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UserTest>'
    test/models/user_test.rb:37:in `each'
    test/models/user_test.rb:37:in `block in <class:UserTest>'


  7) Error:
UserTest#test_email_validation_should_reject_invalid_addresses:
NoMethodError: undefined method `body' for #<User:0x00000008ce4c28>
    test/models/user_test.rb:48:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UserTest>'
    test/models/user_test.rb:46:in `each'
    test/models/user_test.rb:46:in `block in <class:UserTest>'


  8) Error:
UserTest#test_email_should_not_be_too_long:
NoMethodError: undefined method `body' for #<User:0x00000008cf2508>
    test/models/user_test.rb:31:in `block in <class:UserTest>'


  9) Error:
UserTest#test_name_should_be_present:
NoMethodError: undefined method `body' for #<User:0x00000008cfff78>
    test/models/user_test.rb:16:in `block in <class:UserTest>'


 10) Error:
UserTest#test_password_should_have_a_minimum_length:
NoMethodError: undefined method `body' for #<User:0x00000008d05b08>
    test/models/user_test.rb:61:in `block in <class:UserTest>'


 11) Error:
PasswordResetsTest#test_passwords_resets:
NoMethodError: undefined method `body' for #<User:0x000000061021a0>
    app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:29:in `update'
    test/integration/password_resets_test.rb:50:in `block in <class:PasswordResetsTest>'


 12) Error:
UsersEditTest#test_successful_edits_with_friendly_forwarding:
NoMethodError: undefined method `body' for #<User:0x000000085088b0>
    app/controllers/users_controller.rb:44:in `update'
    test/integration/users_edit_test.rb:28:in `block in <class:UsersEditTest>'


 13) Error:
UsersEditTest#test_unsuccessful_edits:
NoMethodError: undefined method `body' for #<User:0x000000082a6798>
    app/controllers/users_controller.rb:44:in `update'
    test/integration/users_edit_test.rb:13:in `block in <class:UsersEditTest>'


 14) Error:
UsersSignupTest#test_Invalid_sign-up_submission:
NoMethodError: undefined method `body' for #<User:0x000000063cb9b8>
    app/controllers/users_controller.rb:29:in `create'
    test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
    test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'


 15) Error:
UsersSignupTest#test_valid_sign-up_information_with_account_activation:
NoMethodError: undefined method `body' for #<User:0x0000000600c340>
    app/controllers/users_controller.rb:29:in `create'
    test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
    test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:25:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
```

The error I get is a `NoMehtodError: undefined method 'body'`, I am sure the problem isn't in the code. There must be a common denominator associated with all these errors. I get ZERO failures in my tests. I am not sure where this error is coming from. I don't have a method body anywhere in the code. The fixtures are not seeding any data into the test application. The code for the first few tests is given below.

```
  test "email should be present" do
    @user.email = "  "
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end


 test "should be valid" do
    assert @user.valid?
  end


test "name should not be too long" do
    @user.name = "a" * 51
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end
```

I didn't include all the test code for all the error for the sake of keeping it brief and to the point. I wasn't exactly sure what code to include to help solve the problem. If any additional code is required please feel free to ask. As always, any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: did you do rake db:test:prepare?

Comment: @user2322409, No i did not, I am not sure what that is actually?

Comment: @user2322409, I googled what the command actually did and it definitely worked. I know what was was causing the problem. Thank you so much!!

Comment: can you post your model?

Answer (score 0):

When we generate a model by using `rails generate` or `rails g` scaffolding command, it will invoke tasks and create some related files for us. One of the files is `test/fixtures/...yml`.
For example:

```
one:
  user: one
  body: MyText

two:
  user: two
  body: MyText
```

In `ActiveSupport::TestCase` class at `test/test_helper.rb`, the setup all fixtures method `fixtures :all` is called when we run tests. We have to modify the fixtures to follow the model attributes. If there is a mismatch between a model and the fixture, it will raise an error. In this problem, I believe there is a mismatch between User model attributes in the table and user fixture in `test/fixtures/users.yml`. Otherwise, please check another autogenerated fixture. There might be a `body: MyText` in the `.yml` file.

Hope it will help someone who faces the same problem